# Malformed key for Project: name-branch:TASK/X00/XXXX-0000. Allowed characters are alphanumeric, ‘-‘, ‘_’, ‘.’ and ‘:’, with at least one non-digit

Tags: sonarqube

I’m trying to create a project on my sonar via Bamboo with a curl:

curl -u ${password} -X POST -H ‘Content-type: application/json’ "http://my_sonar_host/api/projects/create?project=${KEY}&name=${KEY}

Where my project and name are something like TASK/X00/XXXX-0000, but this is giving the error:

Malformed key for Project: name-branch:TASK/X00/XXXX-0000. Allowed characters are alphanumeric, ‘-’, ‘_’, ‘.’ and ‘:’, with at least one non-digit

Is there any way to create using the name and project "name-branch:TASK/X00/XXXX-0000" with slashes?

Here are the project specifications:

Atlassian Bamboo version 6.8.0

SonarQube Version 6.7.6 (build 38781) - LGPL v3 - Community

Comment: What kind of solution are you looking for? The error message is telling you that you can't have `/` in the name. Pick one of the other permitted characters as a separator.

Comment: Upgrade to 7.7? https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-11561

Comment: I need to create my project and name in sonar with the names branch-name:TASK/X00/XXXX-0000, that's my problem, I can't change this slash name pattern with comes from my project

Comment: There is no choice. SonarQube doesn't allow slash characters in the project name. Some tools that integrate with SonarQube have knowledge of that mapping, and can integrate with it properly. If you're trying to integrate a tool that cannot deal with that, then there's nothing you can do.

Comment: It would seem that at least for branch names slashes are supported [since 5.0](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/commit/45ed35bc23e7265bd8eb9bb454f86d7744d39f8d), maybe they forgot to update the API?